# Set attributes for newly created features in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I have a vector layer and `label: "${title}"` is used as one of style property for its rendering. Is it possible to set feature.attribute.title property before feature will be drawn by DrawFeature control? Now for newly created feature I get "undefined" label. Of course I can use "beforefeatureadded" event, but my layer contains many features and I want this event triggers only for newly created features.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem by overriding drawFeature method of DrawFeature  control. See my [pull request](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/568). Now it is possible to set custom features attribute inside [featureAdded](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DrawFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature.featureAdded) function and only after that draw them.